# how to prevent blenderGIS from changing coordinates?

Tags: add-on

When searching for coordinates in BlenderGIS and then exporting the map, the coordinates get rounded to 3 significant digits, and get somehow transformed, thus the origin is not at the exact coordinates given. Is there a way to prevent this?
Example entered coordinates:

**50.987654321, 50.987654321**

Location on google maps:

[image]

Origin Coordinates (Custom property of BlenderGIS):

[image]

As you can see they are not rounded correctly as it would result in 50.988.

Location of Origin:

[image]

As you can see from the two map screenshots, there is a couple of (hundred) meters offset.
Depending on the coordinates this offset can be larger (more then 1 km) or zero.

EDIT:

While doing more research, I was looking through the code of the addon and looked for how the lonlat coordinates get handled.

When searching for coordinates this function gets called:

```py
results = nominatimQuery(self.query, referer='bgis', user_agent=USER_AGENT)
```

and in the code of nominatimQuery:

```py
def nominatimQuery(
    query,
    base_url = 'https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/',
    referer = None,
    user_agent = None,
    format = 'json',
    limit = 10):

    url = base_url + 'search?'
    url += 'format=' + format
    url += '&q=' + quote_plus(query)
    url += '&limit=' + str(limit)

    log.debug('Nominatim search request : {}'.format(url))

    req = Request(url)
    if referer:
        req.add_header('Referer', referer)
    if user_agent:
        req.add_header('User-Agent', user_agent)

    response = urlopen(req, timeout=TIMEOUT)

    r = json.loads(response.read().decode('utf-8'))

    return r
```

A search request is started at:

https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/

Now if I go to that website and search my test coordinates I end up with this location again:

[image]

This to me indicates that the issues lies with openstreetmaps and not with blender/ the addon itself.

When the function is called with the above coordinates this is returned:

[{'place_id': 170014993, 'licence': 'Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://osm.org/copyright', 'osm_type': 'way', 'osm_id': 282100956, 'boundingbox': ['50.934648', '51.1017181', '50.8883715', '51.139555'], 'lat': '**50.978**3397', 'lon': '**50.993**4993', 'display_name': 'КL-10, Зеленовский район, Западно-Казахстанская область, Қазақстан', 'class': 'highway', 'type': 'tertiary', 'importance': 0.001}]

Is there a way to directly enter coordinates with BlenderGIS without using the query?

When changing the custom properties nothing happens.

Comment: i am really curious about this and i am afraid that this "isn't" solvable without changing Blender code itself because i think it has to do with the floating point problem which every programming language has because it has to "cut" somehow the numbers to save them in a low memory consumption way.

Comment: I only have a basic understanding of Python but I thought so as well. I did some research and came across the numpy.foat128. Maybe it is possible to change the add-ons code to use this data type instead of just float.

Comment: Blender itself doesn’t use „Hires“ numbers either so i think just changing the add-on won’t help

Comment: The solution some softwares use with very big yet very precise coordinates is to store them as strings, then parse it to an int / float at runtime and store it back as a string when needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the error in the coordinates is based on the request on OSM that (I guess) searches the nearest location to the given coordinates, I rewrote some parts of the map search class, to skip the query and just use given coordinates. Now the coordinates are correct but of course the query doesn't work anymore (which is fine for my use-case):

```py
class VIEW3D_OT_map_search(bpy.types.Operator):

    bl_idname = "view3d.map_search"
    bl_description = 'Search for a place and move scene origin to it'
    bl_label = "Map search"
    bl_options = {'INTERNAL'}

    query: StringProperty(name="Go to")

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        geoscn = GeoScene(context.scene)
        if geoscn.isBroken:
            self.report({'ERROR'}, "Scene georef is broken")
            return {'CANCELLED'}
        return context.window_manager.invoke_props_dialog(self)

    def execute(self, context):
        geoscn = GeoScene(context.scene)
        prefs = context.preferences.addons[PKG].preferences
        try:


#results directly taken from query without request on OSM

            results = self.query.partition(",") #nominatimQuery(self.query, referer='bgis', user_agent=USER_AGENT)
        except Exception as e:
            log.error('Failed Nominatim query', exc_info=True)
            return {'CANCELLED'}
        if len(results) == 0:
            return {'CANCELLED'}
        else:
            #log.debug('Nominatim search results :{}'.format([r['display_name'] for r in results]))
            #result = results[0]
            lat, lon = float(results[0]), float(results[2])
            if geoscn.isGeoref:
                geoscn.updOriginGeo(lon, lat, updObjLoc=prefs.lockObj)
            else:
                geoscn.setOriginGeo(lon, lat)
        return {'FINISHED'}
```